# Multiple buttons to action on the same window

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

l created two buttons on the same form, and when l click each of them, a new window pops up. l would want them to open the actioned form on the same window.

Find my code in the code block.

Thanks in advance

```
<?php
//Start session
session_start();    
//Unset the variables stored in session
unset($_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME']);
unset($_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME']);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script language="Javascript">
<!--
function OnButton1()
{
    document.loginform.action = "login_exec.php"
    document.loginform.target = "_blank";    // Open in a new window
    document.loginform.submit();             // Submit the page
    return true;
}

function OnButton2()
{
    document.loginform.action = "adminLogin.php"
    document.loginform.target = "_blank";    // Open in a new window
    document.loginform.submit();             // Submit the page
    return true;
}
-->
</script>
<noscript>You need Javascript enabled for this to work</noscript>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>New Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
    if( isset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && is_array($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && 

count($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']

) >0 ) {

echo '<ul class="err">';
foreach($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] as $msg) {
echo '<li>',$msg,'</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
unset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']);
}
?>

<body bgcolor="green">

<form name="loginform" method="post">
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<table width="309" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="5">
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<!--the code bellow is used to display the message of the input validation-->
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div align="right">Username</div></td>
<td><input name="username" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td><div align="right">Password</div></td>
<td><input name="password" type="password" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div align="right"></div></td>
<td><INPUT type="button" value="Login" name=button onclick="OnButton1();"><br/><br/>
<INPUT type="button" value="Click to Login as Admin" name=button onclick="OnButton2();"></td>
</tr>
</table>

</form>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: l think l got the answer                                                                                                                      http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_form_target.asp

Answer (score 0):

In your functions OnButton1 and OnButton2 you set the target to the form to blank (opens a new windows).

Your code:

```
document.loginform.target = "_blank";    // Open in a new window
```

You have to set the target to "_self" if you want the form to perform the action in the same window.

Comment: thanks, that is what l was told using that link. l really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I dont know exactly how to say what im thinking so I hope someone can help me with an edit after but dont you need to attach the functions to a class or the id of a button like so

```
<input type=submit id=button1/><input type=submit id=button2/>

<script>
$('#button1').click(function() {
   document.loginform.action = "login_exec.php"
   document.loginform.target = "_blank";    // Open in a new window
   document.loginform.submit();             // Submit the page
   return true;

});
$('#button2').click(function() {
   document.loginform.action = "adminLogin.php"
   document.loginform.target = "_blank";    // Open in a new window
   document.loginform.submit();             // Submit the page
   return true;
});
</script>
```

you could then even fire off the login php scripts with an ajax call

Comment: the code l posted above works fine, l just wanted it to open on the same window (using "_self" rather than "_blank")